# Node EACCESS error when trying to run composer-rest-server inside a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to run a hyperledger composer sample application "Letters of credit", but it's not working.

Here's the output from "docker logs rest":

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you show us your [tag:docker] command? Or your docker-compose.yml if applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample application starts a number of Docker Containers (including one for the Composer Rest Server).  When the containers are started they map volumes between your logged in session and the Container - the Containers use a default uid and gid of 1000 for the composer user.

You should check the ownership and permissions of the folder (directory) where you start the sample.  The uid 1000 needs to be able to write to the folder where you start the sample.  I have seen this error when the user running the sample is different from 1000 and does not have the correct access.